# ArrayList updating values

Tags: arraylist, compare, compare-and-swap

I have problem to change value at specific position in ArrayList. To be more clear, here is the situation:

I want to add productIDs in one list, and their count in another. But, if user pick product which is already in productList, I want to my count in countList update with new picked counter.

Here is the code:

```
public void compareArrays(){
    if(Variables.productsList.size()==0){
        Variables.productsList.add(product.id);
        Variables.countList.add(count.toString());
    }
    for(int index=0; index<Variables.productsList.size(); index++){
        if(Variables.productsList.get(index).equals(product.id)){

            Integer a = Integer.parseInt(Variables.countList.get(index))+count;
            Variables.countList.set(index, a.toString());

        }

    }
        Variables.productsList.add(product.id);
        Variables.countList.add(count.toString());
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't get in for loop, doesn't make check. Just put items in list. Please help. Thanks ahead!!!

Comment: Should the size property be length for an array?

Comment: The arrays are the same size. I'll fixed this! Just put .add() at the begining, not at the end, then remove duplicate producuts from list.